# How do I hide family shared games in SteamOS?

Tags: steam, steam-deck, steam-os

I have friends that share their Steam games with me using Steam Family Sharing. In the desktop version of Steam I can hide the shared games using "Group by Library", but I can't find this option on the Steam Deck.

How do I hide family shared games that belong to a different user in SteamOS?